# How to use TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) with ASP.NET Identity 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, table-per-hierarchy

I use `ASP.NET Identity 2` in an `MVC5` project and there are 2 type of user classes called `Student` and `Coordinator` as shown below. On the other hand, I tried to follow [TPH (Table Per Hierarchy)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) approach so that using the same entity for both type of users.

```
public class Student : ApplicationUser
{
    public int? Number { get; set; }
}


public class Coordinator : ApplicationUser
{
    public string Room { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin,
     ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
{
    //Custom Properties 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    //code omitted for brevity
}
```

As `ApplicationUser` is already inherited from `IdentityUser`, I did not create it as an `abstract` class and **did not** add it to my `DbContext` as shown below:

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

On the other hand, there is another entity having Student (**not ApplicationUser**) as navigation property shown below:

```
public class Grade
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Grade { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties ===========================
    public virtual Experiment Experiment { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    //public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    //=================================================
}
```

}

However, when adding **DbSet** to `DbContext` I encountered *"Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'Xxxx.ApplicationUser'."* error. So, is there any mistake regarding to the approach above? Should I use DbSet in `DbContext` and should I add ApplicationUser as navigation property to Grade entity? Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: @ChrisPratt Do you have any idea regarding to this issue?

Comment: @DavidG Could you please have a look at this problem as you had already an opinion regarding to my similar question before? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it without adding an `ApplicationUsers` `DbSet` to your `DbContext`, just like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Coordinator> Coordinators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And it is okay to use the `Student` type in the navigation property of your `Grade` entity, you shouldn't have to use `ApplicationUser`.

Check that your database is synchronized with your model. Are you using EF migrations? Your tables in the migration files should look like this: (note the `Discriminator` field in `AspNetUsers` table, and the `Number` and `Room` fields. Those are proof of TPH being applied to the table creation. Also, no tables for `Student` or `Coordinator` were included in the migration.)

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Name = c.String(),
                    Surname = c.String(),
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                    LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    Room = c.String(),
                    Number = c.Int(),
                    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Grades",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    GradeValue = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Student_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.Student_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Student_Id);
```

[image]

If your tables don't look like these, try reverting to an empty database, deleting the migrations and generating them again, and finally updating the database with the good migrations.

I created a dummy MVC project with your entities and just those three `DbSets` in the `DbContext`, generated the migrations and created the database tables, and run the following test code (from the default controller index method). The data were correctly saved in the database:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var student = new Student
            {
                Id = "12345",
                Name = "John",
                Number = 123,
                UserName = "Johnny",
                Email = "some@email.com"
            };
            context.Students.Add(student);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var student = context.Students.Find("12345");
            var grade = new Grade { Id = 333, GradeValue = 90, Student = student };
            context.Grades.Add(grade);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Some questions:

- The "Multiple object sets" error message says something about "The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users'". Where is this 'Users' object set coming from, do you have a Users `DbSet`? Try removing it. Or perhaps you did a copy-paste error with the type parameter of the `DbSet`, something like writing `public DbSet<wrongType> GoodTypeName` (it happens).
- I had problems with this declaration:

  ```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>, IUser<int>
  { ... }
  ```

  So I used this one (no type parameters in the base class):

  ```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
  { ... }
  ```

  It seems that the default implementation of MVC project with Identity expects the `ApplicationUser` to extend the implementation of `IdentityUser` with no type parameters. Otherwise there are compilation errors in several places, for instance when declaring the `ApplicationContext`and trying to use `ApplicationUser` as type parameter of the base class `IdentityDbContext`.
- If you use the base class with type parameters, I think the `TKey` type parameter should be String and not int, unless you have changed the `User.Id` property type in your custom entities. Perhaps you are getting errors because of that? In the database the Id fields of these entities have the type varchar.
- I changed the name of `Grade` property to `GradeValue` (`Grade` is not a valid property name because it is the name of the class, I was getting a compilation error).

If you need it I can send the code of the dummy solution I used to test this.

Comment: Muchisima gracias Diana, I have read all of your comments carefully. I changed the identity type from string to int and there is no problem on that side. On the other hand, the database table has actually the same having the Discriminator and custom columns and there is no extra table. So, it means everything is ok. Saludos cordiales y muchas gracias otra vez :)